# Jest Unable To Find Element By TestID In React Native Styled Component

Tags: typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs, styled-components

I'm trying to write a simple test in Jest that checks to make sure the component `Containers.ImageNameContainer` has rendered to the screen. The thing I'm wanting to test is a child of the  component. It uses styled components and is declared elsewhere in a Containers.js file which is being imported into the component.

I'm getting this error:

```
Component renders successfully to the device
    ✕ renders correctly (1045 ms)

  ● Component renders successfully to the device › renders correctly

    Unable to find an element with testID: imageNameContainer

    <View />

      12 |     it('renders correctly', async () => {
      13 |         const {getByTestId}= render(<Containers.ImageNameContainer/>);
    > 14 |         await waitFor(() => {
         |                      ^
      15 |             const component = getByTestId('imageNameContainer');
      16 |             expect(component).toBeDefined();
      17 |         }) 

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/ProfileHero.test.tsx:14:22)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12)
```

My Component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Containers from '../StyledComponents/Components/Containers'
import ImageViews from "../StyledComponents/Components/ImageViews";
import TextViews from "../StyledComponents/Components/TextViews";

// declare what datatypes are allowed for each prop
let checkins: number
let fanCamCount: number
let coverImage: string | number
let profileImage: string | number
let profileName: string


export default function ProfileHero({data}) {

   checkins = Object.keys(data.checkInStats).length
   fanCamCount = data.checkInStats[1].value
   coverImage = data.image.externalLink
   profileImage = data.person.image.externalLink
   profileName = data.person.name['en-US']

   return (
      <Containers.ProfileHeroContainer>
        <Containers.Profile 
           source={{uri: coverImage}}
           accessibilityLabel = "Profile Cover Image"
           testID="profile"
        >
          

          <Containers.ImageNameContainer testID = 'imageNameContainer'>
            <ImageViews.ProfileImageLink>
              <ImageViews.ProfileImage  source={{ uri: profileImage}} accessibilityLabel =           "Profile Avatar Image"/>
            </ImageViews.ProfileImageLink>
            <TextViews.ProfileName>{profileName}</TextViews.ProfileName>
          </Containers.ImageNameContainer>

          

        </Containers.Profile>
      </Containers.ProfileHeroContainer>
    );
}
```

Here is my test for the component:

```
import ProfileHero from "../components/Views/ProfileHero";
import { render, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react-native'
import Containers from "../components/StyledComponents/Components/Containers";
import React from 'react'


describe('Component renders successfully to the device', () => {
    it('renders correctly', async () => {
        const {getByTestId}= render(<Containers.ImageNameContainer/>);
        await waitFor(() => {
            const component = getByTestId('imageNameContainer');
            expect(component).toBeDefined();
        }) 
    })
})
```

I can't understand why it isn't finding the element. If I search by the component itself it works. I've tried using asynchronous code but that doesn't work either.